# Visual Python 2.7 on Kubuntu 12.04 Segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, coredump, ubuntu, vpython

I have some troubles with vpython. I used it before, on Ubuntu 10.4 but i updated it to Kubuntu 12.4. On Ubuntu 10.4 vPython was working perfectly but now on Kubuntu 12.4 i have some troubles ..

I installed package python-visual with Moun package manager and when I tried to run a simple code, i got this :

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07)  [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from visual import *
>>> sphere() 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I never had any problems with vpython on the same computer using Ubuntu 10.4..

I did :

1) http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1386688
2) sudo apt-get install libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev

but it didn't help...